# Get maneuver phrases by different languages

Tags: flutter, here-api

How to get maneuver phrases by different languages by ManeuverAction in flutter. I am sure it is in SDK because phrases for TTS generation are good.

UPDATE
In this: github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/…, on 148 line - method "describeEnum(action)" return leftTurn, rightTurn, etc. but I waiting left turn, right turn etc, or наліво, направо, etc in different language.

Answer (score 0):

You set the language via ManeuverNotificationOptions and you get the set language as localized text in the ManeuverAction (it seems like this is what you already did above).
Getting more than one language the same time is currently not supported.

Comment: sorry, no it. Thanks. In this: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/navigation_app/lib/NavigationExample.dart, on 148 line - method "describeEnum(action)" return leftTurn, rightTurn, etc. but I waiting left turn, right turn etc, or наліво, направо, etc in different language.